# Free for commercial, Cross-platform GUI library for C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, cross-platform

Please watch the album and the description before answer my question. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJHN2.jpg

I want to make a program in C++ like the images of album(See above for link), but I don't think that the popular GUI libraries can do all the things below.

- Disable the window frame
- Run the specified features in the main window (That means I don't wish the program will open another window for a feature, I want the specified feature run in the main window)
- Using images for window background
- Display specified words for different situations (Example: Display "Wrong password! Please type again" if the password typed by user are different to the account's password that was set before)
- Using images for specified buttons

After searching at Google, I did not found any libraries that match to my requirements.So I came here and ask the question. I wish that a library can be free (without any limits) and also allow me to:

- Use the library in commercial project free of charge and no limits
- Publish my program **without** giving the source code (publish a closed-source program)
- Support Windows, Mac OS X and Linux **without changing a part of/entire code** (Cross-platform with same code)
- Support adding other languages for your program via an external file (Language file)

Comment: [Qt?](http://qt.digia.com/)

Comment: You've updated your question, so I assume you weren't happy with Qt, but you've not explained why that is the case.  Plus your question is still off-topic.

Comment: @dunc123 I dosen't really care about GUI library now, plus I am still learning C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked at [Qt](http://qt-project.org/)?  I believe it fulfills all of your requirements.

Comment: Just make sure to use the open-source version, there is a commercial version that you *cannot* legally use.

Comment: It is not not free for commercial use.

Comment: The open-source version can be licensed under LGPL.  I have used it in a number of commerical products.

Comment: [Qt licensed under the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL) version 2.1 is appropriate for the development of Qt applications provided you can comply with the terms and conditions of the GNU LGPL version 2.1.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/licensing.html).

Comment: @dunc123: Ok maybe it has changed over the years? We have a couple of commercial licences and support since long.

Comment: For some reasons, I dosen't really like Qt, but I will try it.

Comment: @Frodo There are commerical licenses available and have been for as long as I've been using Qt (since Qt3).  However it has also been available under the LGPL and GPL licenses.

Comment: @ngbeslhang: The requirement that *you like it* was not in the list above, maybe you want to update that ;P